# Complete control of various windows computers (home versions included) over lan and internet

Tags: windows, remote-control

I need to check and control my windows computers remotely, with the following requirements:

- without interfering with the users (kids, wife, friends).
- temporarily lock them (and to stop the current user from using it until I release it),
- check running tasks and to be able to kill some of them if needed,
- check available space on drives, etc.

It's OK to install agents on each computer if needed. Also, the same level of control over the internet would be a big advantage.

I've checked several programs like prtg, yamp, remote desktop manager free and several others, but no real solution.

Active directory on a dedicated server (that seems to be the solution) cannot be used on windows home versions and is also complicated and problematic over internet.

I have 2 windows 7 and 2 windows 10 computers (also a win XP but maybe I will throw away in the near future as it is old, but still ok for some games and office tasks).

The Windows 10 home computer is in a different location (so that's why control over the internet is also a big advantage).

How can I do this?

Comment: AD doesn't actually give any sort of control like that – its main task is just central account/password management, you could say.

Comment: Thanks David, anyways, there is no solution? Maybe in the beginning, at least for the first two issues, 1. without interfering and 2. temporarily lock them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some diggin' I think I've found the closest solution to the request: there is a hack named "concurrent RDP patch" that allows RDP on windows home versions and more important, allows simultaneous RDP connections to the same computer, without disturbing the current local user.

There are 2 separate versions for [win 7](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/enable-remote-desktop-connection-in-windows-7-home-premium/) and [win 10](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/releases) and both of them are touching the system files, so there is probably a risk that must be assumed by the user, but until now I've tested both versions without problems.

Initially I was thinking at something more like an administrator console for those computers, but I'm fine with this solution until something more "professional" will appear.

Answer (score 0):

[AnyDesk](https://anydesk.com/remote-desktop) will do what you want. It's fast and light, and has a [free version](https://anydesk.com/order) for occasional private use. You can lock the keyboard and mouse while you are connected, and connect over the internet.

Comment: Thank you, I will test it in deep but what I've seen until now is that this is just another "teamviewer" so it does interfere with the current local user. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on what you mean by "interfere with the user" since you want to temporarily lock them so they can't use it while you are on. If you don't disable the keyboard and mouse then they can use them while you are connected, and a connection dialog does pop up, but otherwise nothing on the target machine changes.

Comment: I was thinking at something like this: 1. Connect to the remote computer without any interference, maybe even without the user's knowledge (not mandatory but it's less disturbing, especially if the kids are playing some game. I don't need to see the desktop, but the running tasks, an overview of the resources, etc. 2. To be able to stop some running tasks or to lock the user or even stop/restart the computer. I was looking for an administration panel or something similar, but the solution with multiple simultaneous RDP connections seems to be ok.